# How to access saved json file by AsyncStorage in layoutRedux file?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, asyncstorage

I'm upldating my app layout by json loaded from api in app.js (saved by reloadLayoutsConfig function). When I want to access my data inside app everything is ok but how can I load layout inside my layoutRedux file?

```
 export const reloadLayoutsConfig = async (newLayoutsConfig) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@LayoutsConfig", JSON.stringify(newLayoutsConfig));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error save user data", error);
    }
  };
```

```
export const getLayoutsConfig = async () => {
  try {
    const LayoutsConfig = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@LayoutsConfig");
    return JSON.parse(LayoutsConfig);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

These two functions work like a charm, whenever I need a value I just do this:

```
getLayoutsConfig().then((LayoutsConfig) => {
   this.setState({ LayoutsConfig : LayoutsConfig });
});
```

This is my layoutRedux:

```
import { getLayoutsConfig} from '@config'

const types = {
  // LOTS OF CODE
}

const initialState = {
  layout: [],
  isFetching: false,
}

var layouts = [];

//  OLD TYPE FROM STORED JSON FILE IN CODE
var layouts = [...LayoutsConfig];

// NEW WAY FROM LOADED JSON FILE FROM API
getLayoutsConfig().then((LayoutsConfig) => {
  layouts = LayoutsConfig;
});

initialState.layout = layouts;

export const actions = {
  // LOTS OF CODE
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  // LOTS OF CODE
}
```

I have mentioned my old and new way to access json file in same code for you to check it. In older version I used to have layout.json file in my code and when I needed to access file i just used it like this:

```
import { LayoutsConfig } from '@config'

var layouts = [...LayoutsConfig];
```

in config :

```
export const LayoutsConfig = AppConfig.LayoutsConfig;
```

but now i call it like this :

```
var layouts = [];

getLayoutsConfig().then((LayoutsConfig) => {
  layouts = LayoutsConfig;
});
```

I get error like layout is not loaded. What can I do and how to call my function?

Comment: What is this file "this is my layoutRedux" ?

Comment: Oh okay, you can't set layout as initial state, as reading the layout is an async action. You should probably dispatch an action such as `LAYOUT_LOAD`  in the callback.